# React Native - AppState 'change' event get no call when navigating between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', ...)
```

The listener does not getting any call. I'm using `StackNavigator` to put root screen and the screen with `AppState`

(Updated) It's been called when I restart the app. But the `Component` where I use `AppState` is not yet the active screen

Comment: try doing this:
componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  }

Comment: it's just the same. unless the docs says the listener function name must it follow exactly. but it doesn't isn't it?

Comment: yeah you are right and its working for me.

Comment: where are you calling this listener?

Comment: as expected, inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: weird thing is the event called when I open app from exit. it been called twice. even though the screen where I use `AppState` is not the landing screen

Comment: we'll need more code to understand the problem. please provide more detailed snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I just want to get notified when a navigation come back to or leave a screen. So I can simply do this

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', ...);
this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', ...);
```

The problem with `AppState` still remains